# website STILL need to redirect from HTTP to https after Nginx redirect config

Tags: linux, http, https, load-balancing

I use AWS EC2 to build a website using load balancer.
However, the pentesting result shows that the website still could be reached by http.
I have checked that in the Nginx config file, we does have a http to https redirect.

```
   server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    # disable checking file size for upload
    client_max_body_size 0;

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
                proxy_set_header HOST \$host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    location /flower/ {
        # rewrite ^/flower/(.*)$ /\$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555/;
                proxy_set_header HOST \$host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP \$remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

    # Settings for a TLS enabled server.
    
        server {
            listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
            listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name  _;
            root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

Why the website still allow the communication of HTTP?

Comment: There is no redirect in your config and most of the directives should be in the 443 server block. See the `return` line in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/337893/505837) for the redirect.

Comment: should I change the server name to actual url in my case

Comment: Having tried to add return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;, still failed to redirect to https, my default is 302 redirect to login page

Comment: You can leave `server_name  _;` and use the host in the redirect, e.g. `return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;` or `return 302 https://example.com/login;`. Move the remaining lines to the 443 server block.

Comment: still redirect to /login instead of https://.../login after I change the config as your idea and run nginx -s reload, what's the problem?thanks